# Create a new random number each time an activity is opened

Tags: android, random, textview

I'm doing a simple addition game on android studio. Every time the "addition" activity is opened I was hoping to generate two random numbers in two text boxes. However I can't get it to work and the text box appears blank every time I run the app and open the activity. Here's my code for one of the text boxes.

```
public void textview2(View View) {
    Random addition1 = new Random();
    int additionint1 = addition1.nextInt(100)+1;
    TextView additionText1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    String additionString1 = String.valueOf(addition1);
    additionText1.setText(additionString1);
}
```

Comment: This code makes no sense in the context you have given, post more information

Comment: This seems to be the method called when you click on this TextView. You must place your code in the onCreate() method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing something here I believe,

In `onCreate` method, you should do something like this..

```
 Random addition1 = new Random();
    int additionint1 = addition1.nextInt(100)+1;
    TextView additionText1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    String additionString1 = String.valueOf(additionint1);
    additionText1.setText(additionString1);
```

but the point is, it should be in `onCreate` so that when your activity is created, the number is generated and `.setText` for your required textView is called...

you can also consider the same if you want to handle other activity states..

PS: Note that you can have this code folded in function and called in overrided method `onCreate`

also, note `String.valueOf(additionint1);`

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
String additionString1 = String.valueOf(addition1);
```

to

```
String additionString1 = String.valueOf(additionint1);
```